# knockout.js: How to update list (call to the server) as filter value changed by user

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a list of items which taken from the server (AJAX+JSON), and filter of statuses of this items that filters the list. I want the list being updated (new Ajax request posted) as soon as filter value is changed. Please help

```
  <select data-bind="options: statuses, value: selectedStatus">
  ...
 <table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
   ...
   </tbody>
 </table>

 function Model() {
      var self = this;
      self.items =  ko.observable();
      self.statuses = ko.observable();
      self.selectedStatus = ko.observable();
 }
```

UPDATE: One of the approach is to subscribe for selectedStatus change inside model like this:

```
self.SelectedStatus.subscribe(function () {
            $.getJSON(...)
});
```

Is it the best way to do so?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you're using AJAX, why not just update the values in the callback?

Comment: The question is how to run the server callback, I do not want to use classic onchange event of the <select>, I want it get done according to knockout concepts with help of observables

Comment: the <select> is a filter for your data?

Comment: Correct, <select> is a filter, as its value changed I need to call server to refresh items collection

Comment: There's really no "official" way to deal with what you want. As you already know, you can either bind to the change event with the event binding, or use a subscription as you showed. Just pick one, or try both and see which you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to orgonaize update - just make a trigger computed observable which will call function that will update list

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/QjHzf/21/)

But I'm not sure that this is a best way.. I think *Subscribe* is most simple way, but dont forgot about loker for ajax request!

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways is to use *[Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)*

[Short Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/QjHzf/4/)

So you can update your items when selected value changed.

Comment: Great job! Thank you for the sample created for me

Comment: The only thing is your example does not request items from the server, I need Ajax request, so I cannot return items immidiatelly, and I can not return them in a $.getJSON callback function for the computed property

Comment: Please see my next post with new example:)